# How to linearly "blend" between multiple 3D points?

Tags: 3d, animation, geometry, blending, tweening

I have a set of 3D points that I need to "blend" between. Lets say I have points [A,B,C] and I have the amount I want to blend each as [0.5, 0.2, 0.8], how can I blend between these points with the amount I need?

Obviously if I just had 2 points I could use the vector math `(A + (B - A) * ratio)`.

**Method 1:**
I'm currently using a weighted average, which I suppose gives me the weighted center, but I need to try different blending styles to see visually which looks best.

**Method 2** What If I did this:

1. Calculated a difference vector, each 3D point against the default point (I do have a default point)

   `A - Default`
2. Then multiplied this difference with the blend amount

   `(A - Default) * Amount`
3. And added these up, would that work? What result would I get?

   `(A - Default) * A_Amount` + `(B - Default) * B_Amount` + `(C - Default) * C_Amount`

Comment: What do you mean by blending here? Do you want the weighted center of these points? If you just want to blend three points A to three other points B you could use your formula with three different sets of A, B, and ratio.

Comment: I need to try different types of blending to see visually which works best. I'm currently using a weighted average, which I suppose gives me the weighted center. Are there other types? See edit;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called a barycentre. Here your point is:

```
P = (A * A_ratio + B * B_ratio + C * C_ratio) / (A_ratio + B_ratio + C_ratio)
```

Badly, Wikipedia have no dedicaced page for this, so you'll have to understand the explanation of [center of mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentre#Barycenter_in_astronomy), which is just a generalization of barycentres applied to physics.

EDIT: your second method is equal to:

```
P - default
```

Proof:

```
((A - def) * A_r + (B - def) * B_r + (C - def) * C_r) / (A_r + B_r + C_r)
= (A * A_r + B * B_r + C * C_r) / (A_r + B_r + C_r) - def * (A_r + B_r + C_r) / (A_r + B_r + C_r)
= P - def
```

Comment: What would the ratios be if I wanted a perfectly centralized point? 0.5 for all? Or 1 for all?

Comment: It is called an isobarycenter, and is equal to the average of all points

Comment: Synxis you are really good in math, but I cannot understand your "P - default" statement or its proof, in simple terms what do you mean?

Comment: `P - default`: `P` is the barycenter defined at the top of my answer, and `default` is the point you've named `Default'. In a nushell, your second method is just a 'wrong' version of your first, because the result will be translated by `-1 * Default`

Comment: No. You cannot set all ratios to 0, because you have to divide by the sum of all ratios, which has to be non-null.